# React Native - Where is AsyncStorage and State stored in Hardware Memory?

Tags: react-native, state

I'm new in React Native.

I hard to find references about location of AsyncStorage and State stored in device hardware memory.

My current assumption, AsyncStorage stored as file in permanent storage (not RAM) and State stored inside volatile memory like RAM.

But, is it really truly like that?

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation on [AsyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage) says:

> On iOS, AsyncStorage is backed by native code that stores small values
>   in a serialized dictionary and larger values in separate files. On
>   Android, AsyncStorage will use either RocksDB or SQLite based on what
>   is available.

And as for `state`, it is stored in memory as you said, and persists as long as the app runs. The state will be gone when the app is closed.